# UseEffect is not called

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I have a question about useEffect. My `useEffect` is not fetching the data the first time, I have to switch route for it to have the data I needed

```
const Comments = ({ ...rest }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const classes = useStyles({ theme });
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { token, loading } = useContext(AuthContext)

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const allUsers = useSelector(state => state.allUsers);
  const comments = useSelector(state => state.listCommentsByBookId);
  const listBooks = useSelector((state) => state.userListBooks);
  const isFetching = useSelector((state) => state.isFetching);
  const [stateReady, setReadyForRender] = useState(false)

  const redirectTo = ( rowData ) => {
    push({
      pathname: ROUTE.USERS_DETAILS,
      user: rowData
    });
  }

  const options = {
    filterType: 'checkbox',
    selectableRowsHeader: false,
    selectableRowsHideCheckboxes: false,
    selectableRowsOnClick: false,
    onRowClick: redirectTo,
  };

  const getAllComments = async () => {
    var allusersId = [];

    //get all ids
    await allUsers.map((user) => {
      allusersId.push(user.uid);
    })

    //get all books from users 
    await allusersId.map(async (id) => {
      await dispatch(getUserListBooks(apiURL + `api/bdd/userListBooks/${id}`, token))
    })

    var listArray = [];


    //filter the array and delete empty rows
    listArray.push(listBooks);
    var newArray = listArray.filter(e => e);
    
    //map every user and stock the list of books in string 
    await newArray.forEach(async (book)=> {
      await book.map(async (book) => {
        await dispatch(getCommentsByBookId(apiURL + `api/bdd/ratingByBook/${book.id}`, token));
      })
    })
    setReadyForRender(true)  
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('is fetching', isFetching)
    if(comments.length === 0) {
      getAllComments();
    }
  }, [stateReady])

  console.log('COM', comments);

  return (
    <div>
     {stateReady && 
      <Card>
        <Box className={classes.tableContainer} sx={{ minWidth: 1050 }}>
          <MUIDataTable
            data={comments}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
          />
        </Box>
      </Card>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Why? It might be related to async await but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch these informations on the first render, you'll have to pass an empty array as the second parameter of your `useEffect`.

The reason your useEffect is not called is because `stateReady` does not change during the course of your current code.

See [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), particularly the **note** section, it explains way better than me how the empty array as second parameter works.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. My bad about the stateReady, i've been trying to make it work using a state which will be passed to true in the fetch function but even without it it's not working..

Comment: Are you still passing an empty array `[]` as second parameter of `useEffect`? Is the `console.log()` in your useEffect is showing?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `stateReady` from your dependency array in the `useEffect` hook. Adding variables in the dependency array means that the use Effect hooks fires only when one of the dependencies changes. Here's how to use `useEffect` as lifecycle methods https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('is fetching', isFetching)
  if(comments.length === 0) {
    getAllComments();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. My bad about the stateReady, i've been trying to make it work using a state which will be passed to `true` in the fetch function but even without it it's not working..

Comment: Hmm, I also see that you're using an async inside your `forEach`, which will not work. You should switch it in a normal for loop. Like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

Comment: Tried with a normal for loop but nothing changed

Comment: Okay, are you sure that all your async operations are being triggered correctly? I mean if you fixed the useEffect hook your react code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace the useEffect section to the below code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
     console.log('is fetching', isFetching)
    if(comments.length === 0) {
      getAllComments();
    }
    })()
   }, [stateReady])
```

You can read more about this in this [link](https://dev.to/danialdezfouli/what-s-wrong-with-the-async-function-in-useeffect-4jne)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) to show errors when coding with hooks. In this case if you want `useEffect` to handle `stateReady`, please provide it in the function `getAllComments() => getAllComments(stateReady)` and when you call this function in `useEffect` with `[stateReady]` as dependencies,  it'll work.